# How to view CActiveDataProvider mysql query

Tags: activerecord, yii

How to get runtime query in CActiveDataProvider as output when searching.

expecting output like
select * from user_tbl where username='xxx' and email='test@in.com';

how can i
In my model

```
public function search() {  

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;  
        $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);           
        $criteria->compare('country',$this->country,true);          
        $criteria->compare('role',$this->role,true); 
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true); 
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 100,
        ),
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the search function returns a CActiveDataProvider.
You can get the "where" part of SQL from the "criteria" property:

```
$prov=$myMod->search();
$cond=$prov->criteria->condition;
$tabName=$myMod->tableName();
$sql="select * from $tabName where $cond";
```

Comment: The question is about how to get generated query from `CActiveDataProvider` before it execute in the database but your answer is is not addressing the question, just getting the condition part of the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate logger in your config file. Please refer to [this description](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9924-logging-sql-queries-while-testing/page__view__findpost__p__48884)

Answer (score 1):

- **First way(Official way):** 
  In your `main.php` config file add these two parameters in your `log section` and you can see log messages at the end of your page or `FireBug Console` in your browser. do not forget to set necessary parameters in `db` section.

`'components' => array(
        'db'=>array(
            'enableProfiling'=>true,
            'enableParamLogging' => true,
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                    array(
                        'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                        'showInFireBug' => true,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
                        'levels'=>'profile',
                        'enabled'=>true,
                    ),
            ),
        ),
    );`

- **Second way:** 
  In your code just change the spelling of one of your columns to something incorrect and you will get an error message contains full SQL query in your page. something like this: 
   *(I have changed `country` to `wrong_country`, when you refresh your page, you will see the generated SQL which was executed in your database)*

> > `$criteria->compare('wrong_country',$this->country,true);`

in the both ways, have `YII_DEBUG` true in `index.php`

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
```